# Is there a way to set a margin for a certain view inside a loop?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am having a hard time putting a margin for my Cardview with a text child.
What I am trying to achieve is to dynamically create a number of cardviews based on a certain number and put them inside a layout.

Please do check my code

```
override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
        val size = NumberHolder.getSize()
        val listOfNumbersLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll_list_of_numbers)



        for (item in 1..size!!) {

            val newCardView = CardView(this)
            newCardView.foregroundGravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
            newCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6200EE"))

            val params = newCardView.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
            params.setMargins(10,10,10,10)
            newCardView.layoutParams = params


            val text = TextView(this)
            text.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            text.text = "test"
            text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            newCardView.addView(text)
            listOfNumbersLayout.addView(newCardView,100,100)

        }

    }
```

But I keep on having this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
        at com.fangs.number_sorter_app.NumberSorterActivity.onWindowFocusChanged(NumberSorterActivity.kt:37)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowFocusChanged(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:124)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

newCardView is not null but newCardView.layoutParams is null, and you are trying to cast null to a non-null type. Remember, kotlin has "nullable *types". The easy thing to do is to create

```
var  param: MarginLayoutParams.LayoutParams = 

    MarginLayoutParams.LayoutParams(MarginLayoutParams.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,100);
    param.setMargins(500,12,0,0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your generous reply. Can I ask a related question?
By saying "newCardView is not null but newCardView.layoutParams is null, and you are trying to cast null to a non-null type", what does it mean?

Comment: If you look at the class ViewGroup you might see var params: MarginLayoutParams, that is a non-nullable type. Whereas var params: MarginLayoutParams? is a nullable type. Notice the "?". These are two different TYPES. 

You could also write
val params = newCardView.layoutParams as? ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
(see "?")
However, you will get an NPE instead.